# Loop to calculate descriptive statistics tables using aggregate

Tags: r, loops, aggregate

I would like to generate tables of statistics described for my dataset, which is a sample with many categorical variables that are a kind of filter to calculate means and deviations.

Here is an example for replication:

```
# example
var1 <- rep (LETTERS [1: 2], 100)
var2 <- rep (c (0.1), 100)
country <- sample (c ("Country_A", "Country_B", "Country_C"), 100, replace = TRUE)
age <- round (runif (100, min = 21, max = 70), 0)

df <- as.data.frame (cbind (var1, var2, country, age))
df $ age <- as.numeric (df $ age)

mean <- aggregate (x = df $ age, by = list (df $ country, df $ var1), FUN = mean)
colnames (mean) [1] <- "Country"
colnames (mean) [3] <- "Age"

lenght <- aggregate (x = df $ age, by = list (df $ country, df $ var1), FUN = length)
colnames (lenght) [1] <- "Country"
colnames (lenght) [3] <- "Age_N"

df_table_var1 <- merge (mean, lenght, by = "Country", all = TRUE)
```

However, I am trying to modify this code with a Loop so that this var1, can be var2, var3 .... generating individual objects. But this is not going well. The database is not extensive, so you are not so concerned about using For

```
for (i in 3: 4) {
  paste0 ("x_media", names (df) [i]) <- aggregate (x = df $ Age, by = list ((df) [i], df $ var), FUN = mean)
  paste0 ("x_sd", names (df) [i]) <- aggregate (x = df $ Age, by = list ((df) [i], df $ var), FUN = sd)

}
```

I believe it would be easier to create a function, but I was unable to do this by allocating the names of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are creating multiple objects in the global environment, it is not recommended, but `paste` on the `lhs` of `<-` won't get assigned.  We need `assign`

```
for (i in 1:2) {
 assign(paste0("x_media", names(df)[i]), 
    value = aggregate(x = df$age, 
             by = df[c('country', paste0('var', i))], FUN = mean))
  assign(paste0("x_sd", names(df)[i]), 
   value =  aggregate(x = df$age,
             by = df[c('country', paste0('var', i))], FUN = sd))

 }
```

-checking the objects

```
x_mediavar1
#    country var1        x
#1 Country_A    A 22.04762
#2 Country_B    A 22.66667
#3 Country_C    A 23.64286
#4 Country_A    B 21.50000
#5 Country_B    B 23.00000
#6 Country_C    B 24.33333

x_sdvar1
#    country var1        x
#1 Country_A    A 12.08295
#2 Country_B    A 12.03252
#3 Country_C    A 13.38107
#4 Country_A    B 11.03371
#5 Country_B    B 16.28451
#6 Country_C    B 13.56466



x_mediavar2
#    country var2        x
#1 Country_A  0.1 21.79487
#2 Country_B  0.1 22.82759
#3 Country_C  0.1 24.03125

x_sdvar2
#    country var2        x
#1 Country_A  0.1 11.53916
#2 Country_B  0.1 14.11747
#3 Country_C  0.1 13.38202
```

---

This can be also done with `lapply` and store in a `list` (without creating many objects)

```
lst1 <-  lapply(names(df)[1:2], function(x) do.call(data.frame, 
     aggregate(df$age,  df[c('country', x)], FUN = function(y) 
            c(Mean = mean(y), SD = sd(y)))))
lst1
#[[1]]
#    country var1   x.Mean     x.SD
#1 Country_A    A 22.04762 12.08295
#2 Country_B    A 22.66667 12.03252
#3 Country_C    A 23.64286 13.38107
#4 Country_A    B 21.50000 11.03371
#5 Country_B    B 23.00000 16.28451
#6 Country_C    B 24.33333 13.56466

#[[2]]
#    country var2   x.Mean     x.SD
#1 Country_A  0.1 21.79487 11.53916
#2 Country_B  0.1 22.82759 14.11747
#3 Country_C  0.1 24.03125 13.38202
```

---

Or the same with `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(names(df)[1:2], ~ 
           df %>% 
              group_by(country, !! rlang::sym(.x)) %>%
              summarise(Mean = mean(age), SD = sd(age)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was just what you needed! Thank you for the accuracy of your response